# An issue with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

This the exception I am getting when I am  trying to run the flutter

```
E/AndroidRuntime(32524): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" on path: DexPathList
```

Comment: have you made the required changes in gradle files while adding your app in firebase?

Comment: There is an issue with that when i tried to implement the firebase message in the gradle file the app got stuck and it didnt run in the virtual device

Comment: try to add `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'` in ur app/build.gradle

Comment: I have tried to add this implementation and did flutter clean, flutter packages get and flutter run, It is showing two error, first error is : E/AndroidRuntime(17081): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.internal.InternalTokenProvider" on path: DexPathList and the second error is [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: , null)